# RSpec: undefined method 'login'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, integration-testing

I have am working on an RSpec test that checks to see if a `user` is an `administrator`, and if so, display some additional fields. When I run the integration spec, it says `undefined method login` and fails. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Here's the relevant part of the integration spec (it works for non-admin tests):

```
context 'if logged in as an admin' do
  let(:administrator) { FactoryGirl.create(:administrator) }
  before { login administrator }
  it 'creates an object upon submit' do
    fill_in 'name', with: 'john doe'
    ...
  end
end
```

In the sessions helper, I have the following (it works in the browser):

```
def login(user)
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  self.current_user = user
end
```

Any ideas of what I could be missing? Everything works perfectly in the browser, but it seems to fail when I run the spec. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of working on it, I failed to realize that I was missing the utilities method, doh!

Here's what made it all work (in spec/support/utilities.rb) for future reference:

```
def login(user)
  visit login_path
  fill_in "E-mail Address",    with: user.email_address
  fill_in "Password", with: user.password
  click_button "Login"
  cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end
```